How many Streifenkarte stripes are needed to get from Munich airport to the city centre?
This website says 7:

"Streifenkarte" mit 10 Streifen - Preis EUR 14,00. Für die Fahrt vom Flughafen in das Stadtgebiet (z.B.Hauptbahnhof) müssen 7 Streifen entwertet werden


"Stripe ticket" with 10 stripes - price EUR 14.00. For the journey from the airport to the city area (e.g. main station), 7 strips must be validated machine translation

And if I understand correctly this one says 8:

Wenn ihr euch eine Streifenkarte kauft, kommt ihr am günstigsten zum Flughafen, Denn 10 Streifen kosten 13 Euro. Für die 4-Zonen-Fahrt zum Flughafen müsst ihr 8 Streifen abstempeln


If you buy a stripe ticket, you can get to the airport for the cheapest time, because 10 stripes cost 13 euros. For the 4-zone trip to the airport, you have to stamp 8 stripes machine translation

Both sites are outdated, the price for a Streifenkarte consisting of 10 stripes is €16.30 last time I checked.

According to the official planner it's 7 stripes. https://m.mvv-muenchen.de/mvvMobile5/en/index.html#trips

The price of a Streifenkarte is now €17 for adults.

Thanks, the official information is exactly what I need - I'll download the app.  In my case it's cheaper to use a Streifenkarte from airport to city centre if I can use the remaining 3 stripes (which I can: Kurzstrecken and/or give them to friends).  I won't be travelling enough to justify a day ticket.  City centre to airport will be a single ticket unless I happen  to have enough stripes left over.

If you decide to go for the stripes ticket, be sure to check how they work. AFAIK (although that info might be outdated, too) you count the number of stripes you want to invalidate and only stamp the last stripe. Don't stamp all stripes you need individually.

The reason for the confusion is that the tariff zones in and around Munich were restructured a few years ago. The second article you are linking to is from 2016 and explains what was correct at that time, that you needed 8 stripes.
Now, you only need 7. You should however consider, that you will not get unused stripes refunded and that it for a short stay in Munich may be cheaper to buy separate tickets instead of using a multi-trip stripe card.
If you travel three or more people together, also note that it is cheaper to buy a group day ticket for €29.10 than to buy single tickets for each passenger. That ticket can also be used for other public transport in and around Munich on the same day.
Even if you are travelling alone, if you plan to use more public transport in Munich on the same day, it might be cheaper to buy a single day ticket for €15.50 than to buy multiple single trip tickets.
